# Multiple category columns and post counting list in wordpress Homepage

Tags: categories

I am decide to make new wordpress website. But my WordPress webdesign structure need home page category navigation bar like directories and it also show only posting counts. Now I am add one sample image,it show how the bar is look like.

- every category needs icons.
- option to change number of rows and columns in category.
- Include exclude specific category
- Auto Update category count when new post published

how to modify my wordpress website to add this category list bar in my home page under the header.
[Sample Image](http://foclist.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/multiple-category-columns.jpg)
Thank You

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'show_option_all'    => '',
    'orderby'            => 'name',
    'order'              => 'ASC',
    'style'              => 'list',
    'show_count'         => 1, // 1 is true and 0 is false
    'hide_empty'         => 1,
    'use_desc_for_title' => 1,
    'child_of'           => 0,
    'feed'               => '',
    'feed_type'          => '',
    'feed_image'         => '',
    'exclude'            => '',
    'exclude_tree'       => '',
    'include'            => '',
    'hierarchical'       => 1,
    'title_li'           => __( 'Categories' ),
    'show_option_none'   => __('No categories'),
    'number'             => null,
    'echo'               => 1,
    'depth'              => 0,
    'current_category'   => 0,
    'pad_counts'         => 0,
    'taxonomy'           => 'category',
    'walker'             => null
);
wp_list_categories( $args );
?>
```

Put the codes anywhere you want to display it, 
If you don't want to display post count , keep `'show_count' => 0` .

For CSS li design, just try it yourself with cool icons. Hope this help you.

You can learn more about categories here: 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_dropdown_categories

Comment: This Answer help me to complete my 65% work Thank you. But now I want to order my category list in 6 columns.Could you know about it?

Comment: @Arun Kumar, CSS is not specific to WordPress (even if they happen in context), see the [FAQ](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq). Try [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) if you need help with styling.